# set environment PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, environment-variables

I recently installed Hitech picc-lite-c 9.81 compiler on my ubuntu 20.04 lts and also i set environment PATH in ~/.profile file as below,

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/hitech/picc/9.81/bin"
fi
```

Then I tried to use picc compiler by hitting the command `picc --help`, It says command "picc" not found, even after I restarted the machine, It says the same. For that, I always sets the PATH by using an export command like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/hitech/picc/9.81/bin`, whenever I am logging in. should i ever want to set an environment PATH whenever i log in?. Could you pls anyone tell me the permanent solution for this?.

Comment: Do you actually have a `bin` folder in your home directory? The part that you modified is conditional on that folder existing.

Comment: i have a bin folder in my home directory

Comment: Hmm. Which desktop environment are you using? The default? GNOME? KDE, something else? Which terminal?

Comment: I am using GNOME desktop env.

Comment: That should normally work. Is it included in `echo $PATH`? I would rather export the executable to /usr/local/bin instead of adding to the path for every possible executable.

Comment: you sure you are using bash? what does `realpath /proc/$$/exe` say

Comment: It says /usr/bin/bash